# XSL fit single image and label to a page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have an xsl document where I need to have a series of pages that each contain a single image caption and then a single image below it.

I do not know the exact image sizes ahead of time, but I want the caption to appear at the top of the page and then constrain the image to be no larger than the remainder of the height of the page or the width of the page (scaled uniformly if needed).

I have tried

```
<fo:block>
  <fo:block>Image Caption Here</fo:block>
  <fo:block>
    <fo:external-graphic content-width="scale-down-to-fit" width="100%" content-height="scale-down-to-fit" height="100%" scaling="uniform">
  </fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

And many combinations of widths/content-widths/heights/content-heights on the blocks and external graphic to no avail. Most often I get the image overflowing off the page either vertically or horizontally.

Comment: Specify which formatter you are using.

Comment: specify `width="100%" height="100%"` on the fo:block around the external graphic as well

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that it is necessary to add the attributes max-height and max-width to 100%.

```
<fo:external-graphic content-width="scale-down-to-fit" width="100%" content-height="scale-down-to-fit" height="100%" scaling="uniform" max-width="100%" max-height="100%">
```